# Let $M$ be a topological $n$-manifold. Then does $H_k(M;\mathbb{Z}) = 0$ for $k > n$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, homology-cohomology

I have the following question:

> Let $M$ be a topological $n$-manifold. Then does $H_k(M;\mathbb{Z}) = 0$ for $k > n$?

We know that for any abelian group $A$ and compact $K \subseteq M$, that $H_k(M, M\setminus K;A) = 0$ for $k > n$, hence if $M$ is compact then $H_k(M;\mathbb{Z}) = 0$.

If $M$ admits a CW-structure, then we also have that $H_k(M;A) = 0$ for $k > n$ for any abelian group $A$. But not all topological $n$-manifolds admit CW-structures, worse still, not all compact topological $n$-manifolds admit CW-structures.

Also if $M$ is orientable (or even if we don't know orientability and just consider $\mathbb{Z}/2$ coefficients), then Poincaire Duality doesn't say anything about the higher homology groups, since we only have an isomorphism $H^i_{comp}(M;\mathbb{Z}) \to H_{n-i}(M;\mathbb{Z})$ for $i \geq 0$.

Which leads me to my question, can we say anything about the higher homology groups of a topological $n$-manifold?

Comment: This is answered here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/360232/homology-of-topological-manifolds

Comment: Also, note that every closed manifold of dimension $n \neq 4$ is homeomorphic to a CW complex,, That is due to Kirby and Siebenmann.

Comment: This is true, see the first half of Prop. 3.29 in Hatcher. Also, Poincaré duality holds for negative $i$ as well, but this result is more primitive than Poincaré duality (and, if we follow an algebraic argument like Hatcher's, deducing this result from Poincaré duality would be circular).

Comment: In addition to what Nick said, every manifold (particularly in dimension 4) is homotopy equivalent to a CW complex of the same dimension, so the result is certainly true, but this is way harder than proving the homology vanishes.